# I get only 5 items from the playlist

Tags: youtube-api

when I make request to get playlist items, I get only 5 items from the playlist.
But they were much more.
who knows how to disable this restriction?

request
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PL7W7Mm4SA4uNAsS33fh3HPlN7ffx7ZdMN&key=mykey

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `maxResults` parameter to whatever you like (max is `50`):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PL7W7Mm4SA4uNAsS33fh3HPlN7ffx7ZdMN&key=mykey&maxResults=50
```

Additionally, you should check whether your result has the `nextPageToken` item. If so, make another request with the parameter `pageToken` set to the value of `nextPageToken`. Repeat this until there's no more `nextPageToken` item.